# Create active transaction past 30 days

Tags: python, pandas

i have data like this

| user_id | date | total_transaction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100222 | 2021-09-01 | 10000 |
| 100333 | 2021-09-02 | 20000 |
| 100444 | 2021-09-24 | 0 |
| 100444 | 2021-09-27 | 30000 |
| 100555 | 2021-09-30 | 0 |
| 100666 | 2021-09-30 | 500 |

i need to filter the data who have active transaction (past 30 days)

active means total_transaction > 0
or
total_transaction < 0 (negative)

I've tried the code like this

```
df = df.groupby('user_id')['date','total_transaction'].max().reset_index()
df
```

but this isn't my expectation.

my expectation should be like this

| user_id | date | total_transaction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100222 | 2021-09-01 | 10000 |
| 100333 | 2021-09-02 | 20000 |
| 100444 | 2021-09-27 | 30000 |
| 100666 | 2021-09-30 | 500 |

anyone can help?

Comment: Please, provide a small piece of code to create a sample of your data. Using images is a very poor habit, as you cannot search for the info in your image and thus your question will never be useful for other people.

Comment: You should also provide the expected output for your sample input

Comment: What does "past 30 days" mean? Just the most recent 30 days in the `date` column?

Comment: yes sir, transaction amount higher than 0 or less than 0. so I can create new dataframe which contain only user_id, date, and total_transaction in past 30 days

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Data given above
data= {"user_id":[100222,100333,100444,100444,100555,100666], "date":["2021-09-01", "2021-09-02", "2021-09-24", "2021-09-27", "2021-09-30", "2021-09-30"], "total_transaction": [10000,20000,0,30000,0,500]}
# Create pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Create a new pandas dataframe grouping by user id and doing the requested aggregate functions.
df2 = df.groupby(["user_id"], as_index=False).agg({'date': 'max', 'total_transaction':'sum'})
# Drop rows where total_transaction is 0
df2 = df2[df2.total_transaction != 0]
```

Result:

```
       user_id        date  total_transaction
0   100222  2021-09-01              10000
1   100333  2021-09-02              20000
2   100444  2021-09-27              30000
4   100666  2021-09-30                500
```

Comment: this code only return user_id who have transaction only on 2021-09-30. i need user_id who have transaction on 2021-09-01 until 2021-09-30

Comment: See the edit. The code picks the max date when a user has 2 or more purchases, but it does not limit purchase by date at all. Have a look at it again.
The result is exactly the same as your expected result.